# Can't add custom fonts, @font/fontname.ttf is not found

Tags: android, fonts

I can't add my font file in the attribute :

```
android:font="@font/Roboto-Regular"
```

I have followed some tutorials and I did:

1. created folder named font in res
2. copy-pasted my ttf font files in it
3. created font resource file
4. - here is the problem - reference ttf in font family XML

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmaxL.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <font
        android:font="@font/Roboto-Regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/Roboto-Regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

</font-family>
```

Comment: Can you make sure your asset folder is under main and not res? Go to Project folder -> app -> src -> main and create  assets -> fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, easier solution was to open my `layout.xml` and to select font-family in attributes. That way you can install Google Fonts which will automatically create font folder in `/res`.

Also, I believe its `android:fontFamily="@font/Roboto-Regular"` syntax.

Comment: indeed that was the right syntax . If i change the font from the phone , it will override my Roboto font tho.. how can I solve this? @benjaminjljn

Comment: Are you applying specific font family to particular widget or globally? You can set global font for the whole app in `styles.xml`, using `<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/Roboto-Regular</item>` and it shouldn't change your font anymore. Make sure you change your Manifest file accordingly.

Comment: I did ```<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/Roboto-Regular</item>``` in the styles.xml , I'm not sure what I should change in the Manifest? what do you mean?

Comment: You can pre-declare fonts in the manifest avoiding the delay of retrieving fonts. Check Android docs on Downloadable fonts.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much , that is helpful, I will look into it